# How to convert text into utf32 encode

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I need to convert my text into utf32 encode like this way.

So how can I convert the string into utf32 encode in php I try to encode method but not working.

```
String: test
Output: 00000074000000650000007300000074

mb_convert_encode("testt",'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'); 

stri_enc_toutf32(str)
```

Comment: Have you tried `mb_convert_encode("testt",'UTF-32','UTF-8')`?

Please go through https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php to know more.

Comment: First of all, it's `mb_convert_encoding`, not "encode". Secondly, there's no `stri_enc_toutf32` function in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$out = mb_convert_encoding($in, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
```

Use `UTF-32BE` or `UTF-32LE` for a particular byte order in the output (see [supported character encodings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php)).

Note, the third parameter is the source string encoding. So, make sure it does match the encoding actually used.

**UPD**
If you want to have a hex text string, then you can convert the binary UTF-32 string into the text using [`bin2hex`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php):

```
$text = bin2hex ($out);
```

Example:

```
  $in = "test";

  $out = mb_convert_encoding($in, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
  $text =  bin2hex ($out) ;

  print ($text); // 00000074000000650000007300000074
```

Comment: From what I've gathered, OP wants to convert input string to numeric values of characters in UTF-32 notation, not to text.